# Google SignIn: GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().hasAuthInKeychain() return false why?

Tags: swift, google-signin

In Swift after signed in then close and open app again GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().hasAuthInKeychain() always return false
can anyone help me please?

Comment: How did you resolve the problem? Can you add that and accept it as an answer please.

Answer (score 4):

Before you check if GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().hasAuthInKeychain()
add your sign in scopes

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes.append("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login")
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes.append("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me")

  if GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().hasAuthInKeychain(){
        print("Signed in")
  } else {
        print("Not Signed in")
  }
```